# Is it possible to remove the $ from nano in linux on longlines?

Tags: linux, nano

is it possible to configure nano to have line breaks on long lines instead of showing a $?

Answer (score 2):

[Nano manual](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v2.1/nano.html):

> Long Line Wrapping Toggle (Meta-L)
>       toggles the -w (--nowrap) command line option.
>
> -r <#cols>, --fill=<#cols>
>       Wrap lines at column #cols. If this value is 0 or less, wrapping will
>   occur at the width of the screen less
>   #cols, allowing it to vary along with the width of the screen if the screen
>   is resized. The default value is -8.

---

Edit:
For the lazy, just edit [nanorc](http://www.nano-editor.org/dist/v1.2/nanorc.5.html):

> set fill n
>       Wrap lines at column number n. If n is 0 or less, the line length will
>   be the screen width less n. The
>   default value is -8.
>   set/unset nowrap
>       Don't wrap text at all.

Comment: It doesn't remove the $.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is possible. I no longer have nano installed so I can't lookup how. But you'll find the setting by doing either [`man nano`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nano) or [`man nanorc`](http://linux.die.net/man/5/nanorc).

Comment: i have already done the reasearch and tryed to find out how to do it, but with no luck.

Comment: Isn't this it? "set fill n: Wrap lines at column number n. If n is 0 or less, the maximum line length will be the screen width less n columns. The default value is -8."

Comment: this is what i havwe tryed, i have the set nowrap and the set fill on but ist not working for some reason.